# Ubuntu 14.04 standard mode boot issue

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 as stand-alone OS on my Asus-1215P laptop a couple of weeks ago. After installation, it worked fine; but yesterday when I turned on the laptop, it went to the grub menu as usual. However, after that it started having problems:

> There was messages like **ACPI Probing Failed**, then **^[[6~^** kept printing. Then another message was that my cifs drive could not be mounted, after that everything goes into a **loop**....**Bunch of lines printing over a over again, Ubuntu loading screen keeps flashing time to time**

I tried to boot from recovery mode and it worked then, but the resolution is so low and **^[[6~^** was still printed a bunch of times. After googling some more, I tried using the command parameter from grub menu multiple times in combination with **acpi=off, nomodeset and nosplash**. Now, although Ubuntu successfully booted using all three options, the performance and graphics of the OS is like booting from recovery mode. So, what should I do to solve this problem?

**P.S: My laptop's 'L' key and "Enter"/"Return" key does not work, so keep in mind that when giving helpful suggestions/solutions**

Comment: if you have no l key, how do you type nosplash

Comment: well, "quiet splash" is already there. So, I just edited that.

Comment: press CTRL + M as an alternative to ENTER/RETURN

Comment: @mchid, CTRL + M does not work as alternative to enter/return in Bios menu. Do you know the alternative of return key in BIOS menu?

Comment: sorry, no; only in a bash shell

Comment: also, to turn off the splash screen, replace "quiet splash" with "profile" instead.

Comment: my graphics card is the built-in intel graphics card and I dont know about installing additional drivers. I see nothing related to nvidia drivers in Software & Updates | Additional Drivers section.

Comment: @mchid, Used "profile" instead of "quiet splash", but the screen went black after using that.

Comment: if you are using intel graphics, *do not*  use acpi=off and *do not* use nomodeset. Additionally, "ACPI PCC probe failed" is a useless warning and safe to ignore.

Comment: cifs has something to do with samba

Comment: yes, I use it to share a folder in LAN network using cifs.utils package and I have added it to /etc/fstab to auto-mount while booting. But that should not cause a booting problem, should it?!?!

Answer (score 0):

I never really got a solution for this problem, but I found a work-around.

The work-around was this:

**I had turned off the laptop and removed the laptop battery. After a couple of minutes, I plugged it back in and turned on the laptop. Now the numerous messages were gone, but the flashing screen was still there. In order to fix the flashing screen, I tapped the *Left-Shift* key for a couple of times and held it down for some moment. After couple of moments, the flashing screen becomes alright and Ubuntu boots perfectly into normal mode without problem.**

I have been using this work-around for four days now and it is still working perfectly. Further, the solution does not add that much time to the standard boot-time.